# What is the minimal number of nodes to run Corda?

Tags: corda

I want to test Corda to see about its capabilities. Is it possible to run just with one node?

I saw some comments that Corda could have run with one thread but it was moving to multithreads and that affected the number of nodes. That was about a year ago.

What is the requirement today? Can I run just one node?

Answer (score 1):

A network requires a notary cluster to prevent double-spends.

In theory, you could start a network with a single node and either:

- Never consume a state (i.e. issuances only)
- Make the single node also be the notary

In practice, this wouldn't really work:

- You'd have no-one to transact with
- You could double-spend by colluding with the notary (i.e. yourself)

But there are no technical limitations on spinning up a network of one (e.g. for education purposes).